# Nginx white page with no error

Tags: nginx

I'm new to nginx. I'm trying to use kubernetes with nginx. But I get a blank page and no error... what can I do ?
Here my configuration :

```
server {
    listen   80;
    root /var/www/project/web;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }
    # DEV
    # This rule should only be placed on your development environment
    # In production, don't include this and don't deploy app_dev.php or config.php
    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    # PROD
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        #internal;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

**Edit :**

I run it in a docker-compose, now I get this when I launch :

> web_1  |  * Restarting PHP5 FastCGI Process Manager php5-fpm

**Edit 2**

> connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file
>   or directory) while connecting to upstream

Comment: Is there anything in the access log?

Comment: No there is not..

Comment: Does it work outside kubernetes?